# strange jQuery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have this jQuery method I call each time my page is loaded, to resize the content of my main div (which is a scrollable one):

```
function resizeMainContent() {
    var newSize = jQuery(window).height();

    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("appsportfolio") != -1) {
            newSize = newSize - 105;
    } else if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("userapp") != -1) {
            newSize = newSize - 128;
    } else if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("password") != -1
                    || window.location.pathname.indexOf("create_user") != -1
                    || window.location.pathname.indexOf("create_account") != -1) {
            newSize = newSize - 105;
    }

    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
            newSize = newSize + 3;

    jQuery("#mainContentPanel").height(newSize);
}
```

Well, on chrome and FF all works great. But, on IE, if this method is called, when I **right click**  on other divs and I show a popup panel, **that panel is not rendered exactly where I've pressed right click but below with about 100px**... If i uncomment this resizeMainContent function, right click works great...

Can you suggest a solution?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
- here is a screenshot with the issue: I press right click on the first `Text` and the popup appears on the second one[image]

If I comment the above jQuery method, it appears exactly where I press right click.

The div where I press right click has this generated code (actually it is uses a `ice:menuPopup` icefaces component)

```
oncontextmenu="Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup(event, 'j_id1378:sectionContextMenu_sub', 'j_id1378:j_id1401:0:j_id1413:1:j_id1414');return false;"
```

so it calls some javascript method from their source code which works FINE (their demo works perfectly) so the problem is for sure not in their javascript code...

Comment: Can you show the code for the right-click handler code as well?

Comment: Are you saying the right-click MENU is off by 100px or that a lightbox style popup is 100px offset? Assuming lightboxes, what is the positioning - relative, absolute, static or fixed? When do you decide where to place the popup - when clicking or when you draw the page?

Comment: Please post the link to a jsfiddle snippet that reproduces the issue in full.

Comment: I've done an update of my post...It's quite hard to reproduce it with jsfiddle and the web site is not yet live...

Comment: I bet the Ice code generates its relative positions at page generation time, rather than at click-time. When you resize it then uses the old corner position and the click x-y INSIDE the textbox to position the context menu.

Comment: @josh.trow - seems plausible what you're saying but then, why it's working on Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they have different code for the major browser types - IE, Gecko, & Webkit. I have seen in a WYSIWYG called InnovaEditor that they do that, and I know that the IE version definitely acts differently than the others (and I can see from the source that it IS different - not to mention less functional). I would throw a debugger on it and step through the popup generation code, see if you could possible override the method or something.

Comment: Seems like you aren't alone - http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-3838

Answer (score 0):

The work-around for this issue I've applied, was to override [icefaces `Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup` method](http://sventon.icefaces.org/svn/showfile.svn;jsessionid=374DB02F499E323E931555686BD0AD1C?path=/icefaces/trunk/icefaces/bridge/component/menu.js&revision=HEAD&name=repo) and apply a -100px for my case if the current browser is IE.

Of course this also means that `oncontextmenu` should point to my method instead of theirs, which I've done in not a very clean way but...at least [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884327/jquery-method-fails-on-ie) works...