# jQuery method fails on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this method:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    var oldName = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu");
    oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup', 'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
    alert(oldName);
    jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu", oldName);
}
```

which works nice on Chrome or FF.
BUT on IE I receive this complaining:

> Object does not support this property or method

and it's pointing me to the 3rd line..

Do you see any work-around?

Ps: I'm using latest version of jQuery (1.6)

**UPDATE**:

I've also tried with:

```
var oldName = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock")[0].getAttribute('oncontextmenu');
```

but still the same problem for IE

Comment: What type is `attr("oncontextmenu")`?

Comment: @Pekka isnt it always a string?

Comment: @Pekka - It's string since versions 1.6

Comment: Not necessarily.  In older versions of IE (with the `getAttribute` bug), it could be a `function` object for event handlers.

Comment: `.attr()` returns `undefined` for attributes that have not been set. It sounds like the `oncontextmenu` attribute has not been set (in IE).

Comment: In IE you can't assign event handlers as attributes.

Comment: @Andy: at least according to the jQuery API docs, `.attr( attributeName )` always returns a string

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already, you should really avoid binding event handlers in HTML attributes. You should make a best-effort attempt at writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), which in this case means binding JS event handlers **using JS.**

Comment: @Matt Ball: then it's lying.  http://jsfiddle.net/5SjWm/show/ in compatibility mode alerts `"function"`, even with jQuery 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with Internet Explorer versions before IE 8.  `attr()` maps to `getAttribute` for event handlers, but older IEs had a bug which caused `getAttribute` to just return the DOM property value instead of the attribute string.

I can't think of a way around it, save for parsing the `outerHTML` string in IE, which you *really* don't want to do :-)

The best approach, for all browsers, is to `bind` to the event using jQuery in the first place:

```
$(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").bind("contextmenu", contextMenuPopupUpdated);
```

And then swap to a different function (`unbind`, then `bind` again) when you need to:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    $(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").unbind().bind("contextmenu", function () {
        Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup();
    });
}
```

---

As you figured out, you can use `getAttributeNode()` to get the string value of the node.  In order to set the attribute, you have to create a function from the string before assigning it.  A simple approach to this might be:

```
function replaceRightClickIcefacesMethod() {
    var elem = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock"),
        oldName = elem.attr("oncontextmenu"),
        fn = String;

    if (typeof oldName == "function")
        oldName = elem[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value,
        fn = Function;

    oldName = oldName.replace('Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup', 'contextMenuPopupUpdated');
    alert(oldName);
    elem[0].setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
}
```

This passes the string to `String` if the original type is a string, which will have no real effect, but if the original type is a function, the resulting string is passed to `Function` before being set as the new value for the attribute.

Comment: @Andy E - Yeah, I understand your explanation. In my case, icefaces generated that oncontextmenu attribute and I only try to replace the call to their method to mine (yeah, dirty way, but it's the single way I can think about...because this has some parameters with random ids which I need them there `oncontextmenu=Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup(event, 'j_id1378:sectionContextMenu_sub', 'j_id1378:j_id1401:0:j_id1413:0:j_id1414');return false;`

Comment: @Andy E - My main problem is that in IE8, it returns function instead of string (Firefox/Chrome)...

Comment: @Cristian: it should be fine in IE 8 if you use a standards mode doctype.  For IE 7 and 6 compatibility, however, there aren't many options available to you.

Comment: @Andy E - thanks again, what I notice is that your update method works nice on FF/Chrome but if I add this at the end: `alert(jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock").attr("oncontextmenu"));` to check if IE has taken the new value it returns: undefined...Can you please check it again? I do not see anything wrong in your method...

Comment: @Cristian: perhaps it's another problem with `attr`.  I've changed it to just use `setAttribute`, which I tested with IE and it worked for me.

Comment: @Thanks a lot. That finally worked. Now, a latest question: this method changes what I want for the first element it finds with that class, only. Can you suggest how to apply a for each here? Thanks again for your time...

Comment: @Thanks, solved with for each: `jQuery.each(elem, function(){
     this.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", fn(oldName));
    })`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it as string instead of function (as it was in IE) like this:

```
var oldName = jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock")[0].getAttributeNode("oncontextmenu").value;
```

Comment: +1, I completely forgot about `getAttributeNode`.  Well done for figuring it out :-)

Comment: @Andy E - yeah, but still a problem I cannot figure out. Seems that trying to change this attribute does not work in IE, even this neither: `jQuery(".singlePaneOfGlassBlock")[0].setAttribute("oncontextmenu",oldName);` - I mean it works without any error, even checking of the new value shows that it has been changed but the DOM, when I inspect it, is not updated in IE...